# Object contains list of object. Find max depth

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    List<A> as;
}
```

I need to find max depth. For example, I can have this:

```
A firstA = new A();
A secondA = new A();
A thirdA = new A();
firstA.addA(secondA);
firstA.addA(thirdA);
secondA.addA(new A());
secondA.addA(new A());
```

I need to return 3.

I tried to do recursive method,

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Do you need to account for `secondA.add(firstA);`?

Comment: set  static variable max_Size=3 in class A.in your addA method check if size is equal or grater than max_size if it is then eirther replace or delete or do whatever you want to

Comment: @bradimus no. there won't be such case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
class A {
    List<A> as;

    public int getDepth() {
        return 1 + as.stream().mapToInt(A::getDepth).max().orElse(0);
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with streams, this can be interpreted as 'add 1 to maximum depth of all children or 0 if there are no children'.

If you can't change A you can still use this by passing A into the method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int getDepth(A a) {
        return 1 + a.as.stream().mapToInt(MyClass::getDepth).max().orElse(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add method to `A` class, but I got how to use this. Now I will try to get the idea. Thank you man.

Comment: I'll add an explanation of how to do it if it's not a method of A.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive depth-computing:

```
public static int computeDepth(A a)
{
    int maxDepth = 0;
    for(A innerA : a.getAs())
    {
        int depth = computeDepth(innerA);
        if(depth > maxDepth)
            maxDepth = depth;
    }
    return maxDepth + 1;
}
```